# How do I do an exact match redirection in tuckey urlrewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting, struts2, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have tuckey URLRewrite on a Struts2 Web application.  I have the following urls configured in URL rewrite.xml

```
   <rule>
       <from casesensitive="true">redeem</from>
       <to>loadRedemptionDetails.action</to>
   </rule>

   <outbound-rule>
       <from casesensitive="true">loadRedemptionDetails.action</from>
       <to encode="false">redeem</to>
   </outbound-rule>

    <rule>
        <from casesensitive="true" >redeem-gifts</from>
        <to>showredeemGiftCard.action</to>
   </rule>
   <outbound-rule>
        <from casesensitive="true">showredeemGiftCard.action</from>
        <to encode="false">redeem-gifts</to>
   </outbound-rule>
```

Now if i try to access /redeem-gifts, my console throws the following error.

There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name showloadRedemptionDetails.actionGiftCard. - [unknown location]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you able to call /showloadRedemptionDetails.action directly from your application? Also check this Struts clean URL implementation: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/implementing-clean-url-in-struts.html

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can override default behavior of StrutsPrepareAndExecute Filter and identify requestUri and invoke the appropriate Action.